# calling pcap_loop from Swift 3

Tags: swift, libpcap, unsafe, swift3

I was trying this code from https://github.com/dfrencham/swiftPCap

```
  pcap_loop(pcapSession, numberOfPackets,
        {
            (args: UnsafeMutablePointer<u_char>,
             pkthdr:UnsafePointer<pcap_pkthdr>,
             packet: UnsafePointer<u_char>) ->Void in
                    // lets handle the result using a call to a singleton 
                    // we can keep state this way, and not have to
                    // tool around by passing pointers to UnsafePointers
                    // and dereferencing later
                    let pa = PacketAnalyser.sharedInstance
                    pa.Process()
        },
        nil)
```

Now it is Swift 3, I cannot compile with the following errors
cannot convert value of type '(UnsafeMutablePointer, UnsafePointer, UnsafePointer) -> Void' to expected argument type 'pcap_handler!'

Not really sure how to proceed, pretty much a newbie at referencing  C code from Swift. I have read the documentation, but not having much luck.

Thanks